# System drops to recovery shell prompt

Tags: boot, nvidia, 20.10

I need help with resolving the following issue:
I had Ubuntu 20.04 and I've updated it to 20.10 version. Everything seemed to be OK until I tried to boot the machine the next day.
I see the loading screen for a few seconds like [this][1]
and then it immediately falls into shell prompt stating:

```
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: recovering journal
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: clean, 861651/15572992 files, 21670193/62263296 blocks
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl-xb" to view system logs, "systemctl" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

I tried to reinstall the OS using an Ubuntu image on flash USB, but the installer doesn't suggest me to reinstall the system only, saving my files/installed apps, etc.
I want to keep my files and installed apps, if I wouldn't I would have just format the disk and install a fresh Ubuntu.
If it matters, I have dual boot with Windows 10, both OS are placed on different physical disks.
My video card is an Nvidia one.

Any help will be much appreciated!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsI5o.jpg